# Какое слово нужно написать: ОБЕИМ или ОБОИМ?

Tags: числительные, род, множественное-число

**Я налью молока (?) щенкам и (?) котятам.**

Comment: @Люся, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Правильно: ***обоим*** щенкам и котятам.

Числительное ОБЕ, а также все образующиеся при его склонении формы, употребляются исключительно с женским родом:
***обе*** дамы, **обеим** подругам.

Всем остальным, т. е. мужскому роду, среднему, а также смешанному "коллективу" (он + она), досталось числительное ***ОБА*** и все его падежные производные:
***оба*** гражданина, **обоим** питомцам, **обоими** планами, **с обоих** окон.

*Мальчик и девочка — **оба** играли во дворе, когда их обоих позвали домой обедать.*

Comment: Все верно. Материал 6 класса.

Answer (score 2):

Оба слова мужского рода - "обоим" и там, и там.